# Dynamic RewriteBase based on server

Tags: .htaccess

How do I create dynamic .htaccess file that recognizes the server path. It needs to work on localhost folder which path is:

```
/Library/WebServer/Documents/myscaryproject/.htaccess
```

and on hosted server path which is:

```
/domains/mydomain/.htaccess
```

This is my .htaccess currently:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /myscaryproject/404.php

RewriteEngine on

# removing index.php from url
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /myscaryproject/index.php?event=$1 [L]

# removing index.php and replacing it with event and page parameter
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /myscaryproject/index.php?event=$1&p=$2 [L]

RewriteRule ^login/?$ login.php  [NC]
```

This all doesn't work if I push it to the server, because pathing isn't correct.

Comment: I tried looking at other questions here, but couldn't find any answers.

Comment: Instead of trying to get your htaccess to be “dynamic”, it would make more sense IMHO to get your local test setup to match the live one. Set up a proper VirtualHost with the correct document root ...

Comment: @CBroe I've been reading about that to be more viable way. So plan is to set up VirtualHost to point at my current project folder, then change RewriteBase to " / " or remove completely. Should this just work?

Comment: Just remove `/myscaryproject/` from your target and keep only relative path as `index.php?event=$1`